# Storing a wchar_t and when showing sometimes it changes some characters

Tags: c++, c, windows

This may be a dumb or weird question but I'm experiencing some weird stuff with my string in my program. This is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct Word{
    private:
    wchar_t wrd[32];

    public:
        wchar_t pword[32];
        void _assign(wchar_t* sender)
        {
            memcpy(wrd, sender, sizeof(sender)+1);
            memcpy(pword, wrd, sizeof(wrd)+1);
        }

};


int main(void)
{

HANDLE ConsCL = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    printf("%s", "Dic size: ");
    int tam;
    scanf("%i", &tam);
    wchar_t* dic[tam];
    Word words[tam];

        for(int i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        printf("Add word %d: ",(i+1));
        dic[i] = (wchar_t*)malloc(33);
        scanf("%s", dic[i]);
        words[i]._assign(dic[i]);
    }
    system("CLS");
    printf("%s", "Succesfully stored dictionary\nBegin writting a word: \n    ");
    int cont=0;

        for(int i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[i].pword);
    }

    //wchar_t* _tword;
    char w = _getch();

    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        if(toupper(w)==toupper(words[i].pword[0]))
            cont++;
    }

    printf("%c\n", w);

    wchar_t* _final[cont];
    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++)
    {
        if(toupper(w)==toupper(words[i].pword[0]))
            _final[i] = words[i].pword;
    }

    //system("CLS");

    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", _final[i]);
    }


    /*SetConsoleTextAttribute(ConsCL, (FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));
    printf("%c", w);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(ConsCL, (FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));
    printf("%c", 'f');*/

    return 0;
}
```

But when I add some words it changes some of the values. For example, check out this examples and it's outputs:

```
Dic Size: 5
Add word 1: perro
Add word 2: perra
Add word 3: persona
Add word 4: santuario
Add word 5: sanitario

OUTPUT:
perro
perra
persona
santuario´ //Why it show that symbol??
sanitario
```

So if I put it like

```
Dic size: 1
Add word 1: santuario

OUTPUT:
santuario
```

Or if I add a LOT of words, sometimes it changes a Word case to Upper case, etc. Is there a reason for this happening with wchar_t ?? If I change all my wchar_t* to char* and wchar_t to char[32] it Works very fine... What's the deal with wchar_t ?

Comment: If you are using C++, why not use `std::string`?

Comment: @gragas I don't like much C++ but sometimes I need to use it. But I just want to know why wchar_t makes that and not char*.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems, here's a list of a few of them:

- In `_assign` you use `sizeof` on a pointer, that will return the size of the pointer and not what it points to
- You use [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which technically is not valid C++
- When you do `malloc(33)` you allocate 33 *bytes* and not 33 `wchar_t`
- In `printf("%s\n", words[i].pword)` you use the format `"%s"` which is for narrow characters (i.e. ordinary `char`) and not `wchar_t`
- As with the `printf` call, you use the narrow character input format in `Scanf`
- Same with `toupper`, it's for `char` and not `wchar_t`

And finally, your program is a mix of (mostly) C and C++, and that will only lead to problems. You have to remember that while C++ have many similarities with C (because C is an ancestor of C++), they still are two distinct and different languages. If you want to use C++ then use as much as possible. For example, use [`std::wstring` (or `std::string` for narrow character strings)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of character pointers and arrays. If you use the classes and functions in [the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) your life as a C++ programmer will be so much easier.

Comment: Ohh you're right! I forgot to change `toupper()` to `CharUpperW()`.
And how can you know the size of a pointer. For example `wchar_t Word = "Hello";` and get it's size is 5 ?

Comment: And yes again, I forgot to change to `wprintf()` xD

Comment: Mmm I want to learn full C first... Kind of my way for doing stuff lol and I got it. The function `lsrtlenW()` instead of `sizeof();`

Comment: @user3718577 If you have a string, it's easy as [`std::strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) (for narrow character strings), and [`std::wcslen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcslen) for wide-character strings.

Comment: @user3718577 Even if you learn C first, and then go on to C++, you have to remember that they are really two different languages and should be treated as such. When programming in C you `malloc`, when programming in C++ use `std::string` or `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` (together with `new`), but you should stay away from `malloc` like the plague when programming C++.

Comment: @user3718577 And to continue my last comment, if you want to learn both languages, learn one completely first, and *then* you start learning the other. Don't mix it, don't use C++ as just fancy "C with classes", then you will never get it right. You can be proficient in both languages, you just have to remember which language you're working in at the moment, and use the features specific for that language properly.